# How to combine separate timeseries labels in Prometheus query?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have the following timeseries entries.

```
ifDescr{ifDescr="GigabitEthernet1/1",ifIndex="1",instance="x.x.x.x",job="snmp"} 1
ifDescr{ifDescr="GigabitEthernet1/2",ifIndex="2",instance="x.x.x.x",job="snmp"} 1
ifDescr{ifDescr="GigabitEthernet5/3",ifIndex="3",instance="x.x.x.x",job="snmp"}
ifHCInOctets{ifIndex="1",instance="x.x.x.x",job="snmp"}
ifHCInOctets{ifIndex="2",instance="x.x.x.x",job="snmp"}
ifHCInOctets{ifIndex="2",instance="x.x.x.x",job="snmp"}
```

As is, I have no way of telling which index matches which description, which makes things confusing.

Is there a way to basically to do a join of the above labels using `ifIndex` to correlate to the the ifDesc label?  Or maybe the job can be used to tie the two timeseries together?

I have looked at the `group_left` feature but haven't been able to figure out how to get it working to combine/aggregate labels.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you want something like `rate(ifHCInOctets[5m]) * ignoring(ifDescr) group_left(ifDescr) ifDescr`

explanation:

Prometheus will only let you use grouping on operations between series. The value of `ifDescr` is always "1" so it's safe to multiply.

The `ignoring` clause means don't use the `ifDescr` label for matching (as it's only on one of the series). `ifIndex`, `instance` and `job` will be used.

`group_left` is specifying what labels you want from the series `ifDescr`. In this case they have the same names.

```
<vector expr> <bin-op> ignoring(<label list>) group_left(<label list>) <vector expr>
```

reference:
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches

Comment: This works but I am lost as to how.  Would you be willing to walk through some it?

Comment: worked for me in similar condition but i couldn't understand what does it do :-)